# C# Stops Executing When Opening A Connection To MySql

Tags: c#, plc, opc

I am writing an application to transfer data from a simulated OPC server to a MySql Database. I am using some of the libraries from OPC Foundation - OPCNETAPI.DLL, OPCNETAPI.COM.DLL.

I have the program reading from the server happily, but it seems as soon as I open a connection inside the loop of reading data, it loops about 5 times and then stops executing.. There are no exceptions thrown and I have tried for hours to work it out and miserably failed.

I've also changed VisualStudio to break when an exception is thrown, and it doesn't

Hopefully some one may know whats going on, but there is nothing obvious, hopefully the following code will spark ideas!

**Windows Forms Code**

```
     public void readplc()
            {
                Opc.URL url = new Opc.URL("opcda://localhost/Matrikon.OPC.Simulation.1");
                Opc.Da.Server server = null;
                OpcCom.Factory fact = new OpcCom.Factory();
                server = new Opc.Da.Server(fact, null);
                try
                {

                    server.Connect(url, new Opc.ConnectData(new System.Net.NetworkCredential()));
                }
                catch (Exception ecy)
                {

                }
                // Create a group
                Opc.Da.Subscription group;
                Opc.Da.SubscriptionState groupState = new Opc.Da.SubscriptionState();
                groupState.Name = "Group";
                groupState.Active = true;
                group = (Opc.Da.Subscription)server.CreateSubscription(groupState);
                // add items to the group.
                Opc.Da.Item[] items = new Opc.Da.Item[2];
                items[0] = new Opc.Da.Item();
                items[0].ItemName = "Random.Int1";
                items[1] = new Opc.Da.Item();
                items[1].ItemName = "Random.Time";
                items = group.AddItems(items);

                    group.DataChanged += new Opc.Da.DataChangedEventHandler(OnTransactionCompleted);

            }

            public void OnTransactionCompleted(object group, object hReq, Opc.Da.ItemValueResult[] items)
            {

                for (int i = 0; i < items.GetLength(0); i++)
                {

                    try
                    {

                        string a = items[i].Value.ToString();
                        string b = items[i].ItemName;
                        string c = items[i].Key;

                        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost;user id=localhost;password=localhost;database=localhost;pooling=false"); 
                        conn.Open();
                        conn.Close();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ec)
                    {
                     MessageBox.Show(ec.Message);
                    }

                }

            }
```

I have set break points throughout the code, stepped through everything possible and still nothing obvious that's causing the issue.

Comment: Did you tried whether you get the data in that iterations? i mean did u checked the `Locals/Autos` in debug mode?

Comment: Yeah, it stills works and I can see the data for 5 loops, then everything freezes, and the Locals/Autos are blank.

Comment: What line does the code stop running?

Comment: "There are no exceptions thrown" - you've got a style of coding which makes it far from easy to say that. Empty `catch` blocks is almost always a bad sign (especially catch-all blocks which catch `Exception`). If you can't do something reasonable with an exception, it's better to let it escape and break the program in an obvious way relating to the original problem, rather than to hide all of the evidence and carry on regardless.

Comment: Thats right. Remove the try catch blocks or catch the exception and do something sensible to see if you actually get the Error/Exception or not.

Comment: I've already tried having  MessageBox.Show(ec.Message); in there, no difference, no exception thrown

Comment: Can you check whether the closed connections are really closed? Use `show processlist` on the mysql admin interface/command line. If not, try disposing the connections by putting the connection in a `using` block.

Comment: I have tried the code with a using block, still doesn't make a difference, I have tried everything I possibly can think off.